# Unresolved reference: getPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store a boolean value which is changed every time a button is clicked. I want to do this using shared preferences, however I keep running into this error: 
    Unresolved reference: getPreferences

This is my code:

```
btnStyle.setOnClickListener() {
            styleHasChanged = !styleHasChanged;

            if(styleHasChanged  == true){
                btnStyle.setText("true")
            }else{
                btnStyle.setText("false")
            }

          //  AppUtil.saveConfig(activity, config)
          //  EventBus.getDefault().post(ReloadDataEvent())

          var sharedPref : SharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            var editor = sharedPref.edit()
            editor.putBoolean("bla", styleHasChanged)
            editor.commit()



        }
```

Comment: Show your stacktrace error.

Comment: It will not compile.
On the following line: 
var sharedPref : SharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
the letters getPreferences are red and when I hover over them I receive this:
Unresolved reference: getPreferences

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this a `Fragment` or an `Activity`? This seems code written in fragment or somewhere else. Because `getPreferences()` is method of activity and you need to have Activity's instance to call it .

Just have a Activity instance and call it as below . example for Fragment:-

```
btnStyle.setOnClickListener() {
        styleHasChanged = !styleHasChanged;
        if(styleHasChanged  == true){
            btnStyle.setText("true")
        }else{
            btnStyle.setText("false")
        }
        val sharedPref : SharedPreferences?= activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPref?.edit()?.putBoolean("bla", styleHasChanged)?.apply()
    }
```

Comment: Yup, this works. The code is written in a fragment and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 14):

For <kbd>**KOTLIN**</kbd>

If Activity then use **`this@ActivityName`**

```
var sharedPref : SharedPreferences = this@ActivityName.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If Fragment then use **`activity!!`**

```
var sharedPref : SharedPreferences = activity!!.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to open sharedPreferences via application context, like this:

```
application.getSharedPreferences("Your preference name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

All you need is context for opening preferences.

Comment: In the line you suggested application becomes the unresolved reference.

Comment: Show  screenshot of your error or attach more code of your case.

Comment: This work in my case since I am using non Activity/Fragment class to get the preferences, thank you Sir!