# Get reference to getSharedPreferences outside fragment or activity

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

> Thanks for stopping by! Not a duplicate of [Unresolved reference: getPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662832/unresolved-reference-getpreferences) as they had an issue with fragment and I had issues with abstract classes

I am creating an `abstract` class named Inspector.
This class will mostly be for inspecting low-level stuff like if the app was run for the first time or is the internet working, etc.

Here is my first implementation of checking the first run:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences

abstract class Inspector{
    private var PRIVATE_MODE = 0
    private var firstRun : String = "first_run"

    //Function returns if the app was run for the first time or not
    fun firstRun(): Boolean{
        return checkPref(firstRun)
    }

    private fun checkPref(PREF_NAME : String): Boolean {
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
        return sharedPref.getBoolean(PREF_NAME, false)
    }
}
```

That's all I have in my `Inspector.kt` file. However I've been stuck at this issue:

`Unresolved reference: getSharedPreferences`

I have created this in a class that doesn't do anything yet.

- What could be the cause of this error?
- How do I fix it?
- Is it because my class doesn't extend `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662832/unresolved-reference-getpreferences 
To summarize: "getPreferences() is method of activity and you need to have Activity's instance to call it".

Comment: @Oskarzito no. it doesn't. Did you just flag to close it?

Comment: no? Did I? Sorry if so, just checked for duplicate, wasn't meant to flag :)

Comment: @Oskarzito ok, that's not an issue. However, I've already accepted an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences` method needs an associated context as you can see from [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). In your abstract class you haven't any context (whereas you have a context in an Activity or Fragment).
Since you are writing a concrete method into an abstract class you need to pass the **context** in the class constructor, in order to get access to sharedPreferences:

```kotlin
abstract class Inspector(private val context : Context){
    private var PRIVATE_MODE = 0
    private var firstRun : String = "first_run"

    //Function returns if the app was run for the first time or not
    fun firstRun(): Boolean{
        return checkPref(firstRun)
    }

    private fun checkPref(PREF_NAME : String): Boolean {
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
        return sharedPref.getBoolean(PREF_NAME, false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass context as a constructor argument
Please change your class with the following code.
I hope it helps you

```
abstract class Inspector(val context: Context){
    private var PRIVATE_MODE = 0
    private var firstRun : String = "first_run"

    //Function returns if the app was run for the first time or not
    fun firstRun(): Boolean{
        return checkPref(firstRun)
    }

    private fun checkPref(PREF_NAME : String): Boolean {
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
        return sharedPref.getBoolean(PREF_NAME, false)
    }
}
```

Pass activity or fragment object in constructor argument when you create class object.